# How to make a game object from several game objects in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, object

I have programmed a great music game. Unfortunately there is a problem. In my game there are so many objects that my smartphone can't load the game properly. I have nowhere to find out how to make an object out of many objects. If someone knows how to do it I would be very happy!

My Script:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class line : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    //Please attach me to the line, then set  dline,tail,mcamera,road,decorates,dieeff.
    //You can add more to make this better!
    public GameObject dline, tail, mcamera, road, decorates, dieeff;

    private GameObject tempgo, tempdia, tempcr;

    public bool direction, alive, start, load, roadmaker;

    public float cameraspeed, temprm;

    public Vector3 offset, tempcrgo;

    private GameObject[] dia, cr;

    List<GameObject> go = new List<GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {
        start = false;
        load = true;
        alive = true;
        //find diamonds and crowns
        dia = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("dia");
        cr = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("crown");
        //
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (load == true)
        {
            //save the initial distance between camera and line
            offset = mcamera.transform.position - dline.transform.position;
            cameraspeed = 0.03f;
            load = false;
            //
        }
        //restart
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) == true)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("main");
        }
        //
        if (start == false && alive == true)
        {//start game
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) == true || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true)
            {
                start = true;
                dline.GetComponent<AudioSource>().enabled = true;
            }

        }//

        if (start == true)
        {//turn
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) == true || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true)
            {
                if (direction == true)
                {
                    direction = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    direction = true;
                }
            }
        }//
         //build road/wall more efficiently
        if (roadmaker)
        {
            temprm += 1;
            //why there is temprm?to reduce the amount of roads
            //why build one when click?to ensure there is road/wall when line turns(or it will look weird)
            if (temprm % 6 == 1 || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) == true || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true)
            {
                GameObject.Instantiate(road, dline.transform.position + new Vector3(3, 0, -3), dline.transform.rotation);
                GameObject.Instantiate(road, dline.transform.position + new Vector3(-3, 0, 3), dline.transform.rotation);
            }// // //
        }
        else
        {//when you play ...I dont put the part in Update but if(roadmaker) because these actions will create new gameobject and interfere the copying of road
            GameObject.Instantiate(tail, dline.transform.position, dline.transform.rotation);
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) == true || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true)
            {
                if (direction == true)
                {
                    go.Add(GameObject.Instantiate(decorates, dline.transform.position + new Vector3(8, -9, -5), dline.transform.rotation));
                }
                else
                {
                    go.Add(GameObject.Instantiate(decorates, dline.transform.position + new Vector3(-5, -9, 8), dline.transform.rotation));
                }
            }
        }//
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {//smooth camera
        mcamera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(mcamera.transform.position, offset + dline.transform.position, cameraspeed);
        //
        //some 'animations' .I didnt use animation component because I dont know how it works in Unity :(
        foreach (GameObject tempgo in go)
        {
            tempgo.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0.2f, 0);
        }

        foreach (GameObject tempdia in dia)
        {
            tempdia.transform.localEulerAngles += new Vector3(0, 2, 0);
            if (Mathf.Abs(dline.transform.position.x - tempdia.transform.position.x) < 1 && Mathf.Abs(dline.transform.position.z - tempdia.transform.position.z) < 1 && tempdia.transform.localScale.z > 0)
            {
                tempdia.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
            }
        }
        foreach (GameObject tempcr in cr)
        {
            tempcr.transform.localEulerAngles += new Vector3(0, 2, 0);
            if (Mathf.Abs(dline.transform.position.x - tempcr.transform.position.x) < 2 && Mathf.Abs(dline.transform.position.z - tempcr.transform.position.z) < 2 && tempcr.transform.localScale.z > 0)
            {
                tempcr.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.26f, 0.26f, 0.26f);
                tempcrgo = tempcr.transform.position;
            }
            if (tempcr.transform.localScale.z <= 0)
            {
                tempcrgo += new Vector3(Random.Range(-2f, 2f), Random.Range(-1f, 2f), Random.Range(-2f, 2f));
                tempcr.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = true;
                tempcr.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(tempcr.transform.position, tempcrgo, 0.02f);

            }
        }
        //
        if (start == true && alive == true)
        {//how the line move
            if (direction == true)
            {
                dline.transform.position += new Vector3(0.3f, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                dline.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, 0.3f);
            }
        }//
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision x)
    {//when die...
        if (x.collider.tag == "wall")
        {
            alive = false;
            mcamera.GetComponent<AudioSource>().enabled = true;
            dieeff.SetActive(true);
        }// 
         //when complete the level...
        if (x.collider.tag == "Finish")
        {
            offset = offset + offset + offset + offset;
            cameraspeed = 0.01f;
        }//
    }
}

`
```

Video Link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dqIqu6tx5thNbCJ1jNndXEJY_a9JJGGe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please define "make one object out of many objects" more exactly. Are you talking about meshes .. or entire GameObjects meaning including their attached components etc ?

Comment: In general you should use the Profiler in order to see what exactly is using up your resources and causing these lags .. it is most probably you using `Instantiate` **every frame!!** maybe even multiple times per frame ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave us nothing about your game. It is something like piano tiles? If so, you should destroy the objects that instantiated when objects out of camera range. Also you do everything on update. Be careful about it! It works every frame not every second. For standard mobile that 30 update call per second. Also, if you wish to spawn a lot of object, you should use special algorithm like [Object Pooling In Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdSmKaJvCoA)

Also you set every variable on update. Is it really necessary? I don't think but you never give us a clue about your game. Good luck!